# Dice Game, ends after one game

Tags: javascript, html

My game works, but when you click on play button, the games plays once and then when you click on play again nothing happens.

Would appreciated any help.

I would have thought the click event listener would run the load game function after every click but it does not.

I'm sure its something simple I'm doing wrong.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dice Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <h2 class="result">Click Play!!!</h2>
        <div class="players">
          <span>Player 1</span>
          <span>Player 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="scores">
          <img class="dice_a" />
          <img class="dice_b" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="play_btn">Play</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const play_btn = document.querySelector(".play_btn");

const dice_a = document.querySelector(".dice_a");
const dice_b = document.querySelector(".dice_b");

const randomNo1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
const randomNo2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

const loadGame = () => {
  dice_a.src = `images/${randomNo1}.png`;
  dice_b.src = `images/${randomNo2}.png`;
  if (randomNo1 > randomNo2) {
    result.innerText = "Player 1 Wins!";
  }

  if (randomNo1 < randomNo2) {
    result.innerText = "Player 2 Wins!";
  }

  if (randomNo1 === randomNo2) {
    result.innerText = "Draw";
  }
};

play_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loadGame();
});
```

Comment: The problem is a bit vague, but note how you're generating the random numbers (dice) outside of `loadGame`, so those numbers will only ever be generated once. If you want new numbers each time, those need to be generated when `loadGame` is called. I'm guessing since the results are always the same, the message will remain the same, so it looks like "nothing happens".

Comment: That fixed my problem, silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

As Carcigenicate explained, the random numbers are only calculated during load time and not when `loadGame` is run. Just move the variable declaration in the beginning of the function and you have the expected outcome.

```js
const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const play_btn = document.querySelector(".play_btn");

const dice_a = document.querySelector(".dice_a");
const dice_b = document.querySelector(".dice_b");


const loadGame = () => {
  var randomNo1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var randomNo2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  dice_a.src = `images/${randomNo1}.png`;
  dice_b.src = `images/${randomNo2}.png`;
  if (randomNo1 > randomNo2) {
    result.innerText = "Player 1 Wins!";
  }

  if (randomNo1 < randomNo2) {
    result.innerText = "Player 2 Wins!";
  }

  if (randomNo1 === randomNo2) {
    result.innerText = "Draw";
  }
};

play_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loadGame();
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dice Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <h2 class="result">Click Play!!!</h2>
        <div class="players">
          <span>Player 1</span>
          <span>Player 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="scores">
          <img class="dice_a" />
          <img class="dice_b" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="play_btn">Play</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```